# How to create an unattended robot in UiPath Orchestrator?

Tags: uipath, uipath-activity, uipath-api

I have a robot created in Studio and published to Orchestrator but I can’t manage to run it as an unattended robot.

I can create the robot and create a process but when I try to run the process the robot I created is not visible.

Comment: It seems this question is not about Robot Framework, if so please remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

My experience has been that the Environment creation and subsequent robot association is typically the step missed when creating a UiPath robot. Check that first. Hopefully the solution will be as simple as addressing that.

**/tl;dr**

### Robot creation

There's a fair bit to unpack here, and while there are a few places you can go wrong when you [create UiPath robots](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Create-your-first-RPA-robot-to-UiPath-Orchestrator-tutorial), it's not a particularly onerous task once you've done it a few times.

Here's how you do it, from start to finish:

1. Publish your code to Orchestrator
2. Create a machine in Orchestrator and connect to it with UiPath Assistant
3. Create the unattended robot
4. Add the robot to an environment
5. Create the process to map the code to the robot

It seems like you've got step 1 and 2 down, as you can't publish without a machine created and UiPath Assistant configured. So the issue is somewhere in steps 3, 4 and 5.

Here's what the page to create an unattended robot looks like:

[image]

Errors commonly occur on this page. Please make sure:

- The robot is of type unattended, not Studio or StudioPro. Support for those is going away
- Make sure the Machine* name maps exactly to the hostname of the machine on which the robot will run
- Make sure the Domain\username field maps exactly to the results of the `whomai` command in a command prompt
- Make sure the password is for the account used for the username listed in the `whomai` call. This is not the UiPath Orchestrator password. It is the password for the Windows machine running the robot

### Don't forget the environment tab

After you create the robot, make sure you go to the Environment tab, create an environment, and associate the robot with that environment. This step is commonly missed, and without it, your robot will not show up when you go to run your process. My guess is this is most likely the missing step.

[image]

With the robot created, the environment configured, and the UiPath Assistant configured with a connection to the machine listed in the management section of UiPath Orchestrator, you should be able to create a new [UiPath process](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-create-a-UiPath-Orchestrator-process-to-run-your-RPA-robots), and when you go to run the process, the robot you just created will be listed as a possible job target.